# How to send data from javascript to servlet inside url

Tags: javascript, java, servlets

this is my javascript code

```
$('a').click(function() {
    ty = $(this).index();
    de = document.getElementsByTagName('klw')[ty].innerHTML;
    alert("this is " + de);
});
```

want to send "de" data from $('a') to the other method that is

```
function jill() {
    alert("hi" + de);

    document.location.href = "openmessage";
};
```

`openmessage` is the name of servlet. And from here to the servlet and how to print it on the servlet

Comment: How do you want to send that data ? As a `GET` request you can send it using `document.location.href="openmessage?de=" + de;`. For other request types, use a `<form>` element.

Comment: Thanks sachin,I got the solution it is working fine